# Deletion from btree - pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: c, pointers, tree, binary-tree

I am getting a 'pointer being freed was not allocated' error. Now I know that the node actually exists in my tree (given that my insertions & searching works), but I'm getting an error when I go to delete a node. Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated.

```
int set_delete(set_t *set, int del_val)
{
    /* TODO: readd delete child nodes */

    struct tree_node *node;

    node = set->root;
    *node = tree_search(&node, del_val);

    if (node != NULL) {
        free(node);
        return 1;
    }


    return 0;   
}

struct tree_node tree_search(struct tree_node **node, int search_val) {
    if(!(*node)) {
        return **node;
    }

    if ((*node)->val == search_val) {
        return **node;
    } else if ((*node)->val > search_val) {
        tree_search(&(*node)->left, search_val);
    } else if ((*node)->val < search_val) {
        tree_search(&(*node)->right, search_val);
    }

    return **node;

}
```

Comment: Hint: you are returning a **copy** of a node. That copy lives on the stack and was **never** allocated using `malloc` so you cannot just pass it to `free`.

Comment: First of all, you don't assign to `*node` anywhere in `tree_Search` so there's no use in passing a pointer to the pointer. Secondly, you don't return the pointer, but return by value. Thirdly, there are two branches in the function that you don't change the node or what it points to. Summary: Your search function is very flawed.

Answer (score 0):

As Nik Bougalis and Joachim Pileborg have pointed out, the issue is with the return value of tree_search. You have to return a pointer to the node so that it can be deleted using free, assuming of course it was originally allocated using malloc.

```
struct tree_node * tree_search( struct tree_node *node, int search_val)
{
      if( node == 0 )
      {
         return 0; // not found
      }
      if( node->val == search_val)
      {
         return node; // found
      }
      if( node->val > search_val)
      {
          return tree_search( node->left, search_val); // search left tree
      }
      return tree_search( node->right, search_val); // search right tree
}
```